# Does the initial part of voiced consonants always have a low pitch?

Tags: phonetics, consonants, voicing

The spectral graphs in the accepted answer of "[What is the difference between voiced and voiceless stop consonants?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-difference-between-voiced-and-voiceless-stop-consonants)" shows that in English, the initial part (before the stop release) of voiced stop consonants has a lower pitch compared to the vowel that follows. Is it true for all voiced consonants in English? Does the same apply to other languages as well?

Answer (score 7):

In general, yes--the F0 (fundamental frequency) of the voicing during a stop closure is going to be lower than that of the following vowel. The fact that there is a full closure in the oral tract (for non-nasal stops) means that there is nowhere for the air coming out of the lungs to escape, making it difficult to maintain a high velocity of air through the glottis and thus slowing down vocal fold vibration. When the oral cavity is opened for the release of the stop, the built-up pressure causes the air to rush out initially, making for a higher rate of vocal fold vibration.

I tried recording myself producing some voiced stops in various contexts, and the only time I observed a partial exception to the above generalization was when the voiced stop was between two vowels and the first vowel had a much higher F0 than the second vowel.  In that case, the incoming F0 had enough "momentum" to give at least the earlier part of the stop voicing a higher F0 than the following vowel:

[image: spectrogram and pitch curve for 'aba?']

However, even in that case, the vocal fold vibration toward the end of the stop appears to slow down to a rate that is slightly lower than the initial F0 of the following vowel.

I would expect this effect to be a language-general one, since it has to do with the mechanics of airflow through the vocal tract.